# Why does this code not actually shut down my PC?

Tags: c#

I'm new so please don't judge too hard.

I want to shut down the pc after the timer ends. But nothing happens.

Just text so I can post this

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1  
{
    public partial class Form3 : Form 
    {
        public Form3()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int time = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);

            timer.Interval = time * 1;
            timer.Start();
        }

        private void Form3_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(timer.Interval.Equals(1))
            {
                Process.Start("shutdown", "/s /t 0");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Add break points to determine if you are getting into the button click event and the tick event.  You need to register events using '+='

Comment: Heya! Please bear in mind that if you want people to help you with your issues / answer your questions, you need to provide example code that's sufficient to assess the issue.
As is, your code here wouldn't really help anyone be able to help you after.

That aside, double check your `timer` class documentation. If its the `System.Timers.Timer` class, then  there are several little issues.
Interval -> length of time between "ticks". So already, you're assigning whatever time you parse from your text (the *1 is pointless btw).
And if you registered your timer_Tick method, it'll never = 1.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting timer.Interval from a textbox value. And there is a condition which should be provided in order to trigger the Process.Start method.

```
if(timer.Interval.Equals(1))
{
    Process.Start("shutdown", "/s /t 0");
}
```

If user do not enter "1" to the textbox, then this code will not be executed.

Keep in mind that timer.Interval should be in milliseconds. 1 means 1 millisecond, which is nearly immediate.